# Is there a standard notation for off-diagonal transpose?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Given a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$,
its transpose, obviously, is $A^T=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$.
But is there a conventional way of notating the matrix
 $\begin{pmatrix}d&b\\c&a\end{pmatrix}$
in terms of $A$?
This generalizes in an obvious way to larger matrices.
Also, do you know of some instance where this has been useful, especially in a geometric application?

I realize this seems like a dumb question, but I'm working on something where this matrix operation has come up in a significant way.  It would be nice to see if anyone has had something similar happen.

For now I've been using $A_T$.

Comment: Without introducing new notations, this is $PA^TP$, with the matrix $P=[[0,1],[1,0]]$ .

Comment: Yes that is clear but what I really want is something more concise.  My use of it has it happening so regularly, I wouldn't want to write it out as a matrix product every time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701936 (Fuchsian equations of type DN, by Vasily Golyshev and Jan Stienstra) the transpose of the matrix $A$ with respect to the anti-diagonal is denoted by $A^\tau$. It relates to the ordinary transpose $A^T$
(or $A^t$ as used in the paper), as follows:
$$A^\tau=JA^TJ$$
where $J=(J_{ij})_{0\le i,j\le n}$ denotes the matrix with $J_{ij}=1$ if $i+j=n$
and $J_{ij}=0$  otherwise. This fact was already noted by Pietro Majer for the case $n=1$ with notation $P$ instead of $J$ used in the Golyshev and Stienstra paper.

Comment: This is very nice.  I also like the fact that they use a $J$.  I don't know if it's a coincidence, but under the standard matrix representation $\rho$ of a quaternion algebra, the quaternion usually denoted by $j$ provides $\rho(jqj)^t=\rho(q)^{\tau}$ for any quaternion $q$.  There's a hint of how I came to find a use for this by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the transpose is defined around the diagonal and, to the best of my knowledge, the other diagonal is dubbed 'anti-diagonal', I think a natural extension would be call it 'anti-transpose' and write it $A^{aT}$.

Comment: I would think a good way of writing it would be $A^{T'}$, but I don't know if that is used for some other purpose.